# TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get date from pickle file and add one day to the date. The print statement returns **2018-09-10** . Then getting error  `'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'`  on `datetime.datetime.strftime(dataHist['last_updated'], '%Y-%m-%d')` line

```
Import pickle

dataHistFile = open('dat.pkl', 'rb')
dataHist = pickle.load(dataHistFile, encoding='bytes')
print(dataHist['last_updated'])
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strftime(dataHist['last_updated'], '%Y-%m-%d')
date = dt_obj + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

> 2018-09-10
>    File "C:/Users/Arvinth
>   Kumar/Downloads/strtsmrt-master/gendata.py", line 81, in init
>       fetchData()   File "C:/Users/Arvinth Kumar/Downloads/strtsmrt-master/gendata.py", line 15, in fetchData
>       news.init()   File "C:\Users\Arvinth Kumar\Downloads\strtsmrt-master\news.py", line 58, in init
>       getNews()   File "C:\Users\Arvinth Kumar\Downloads\strtsmrt-master\news.py", line 38, in getNews
>       dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strftime(dataHist['last_updated'], '%Y-%m-%d') TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a
>   'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Please help!

Comment: What do you see for `type(dataHist)`? and `type(dataHist['last_updated'])`?

Comment: I think you want [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a demo for you to show the difference between **strptime** and **strftime**.

```
import datetime


def datetime_datetime_strptime():
    _datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        "2018-09-09 18:47:30",
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    )
    print(str(_datetime))


def datetime_datetime_strftime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))   # 2018/09/09
    print(now.__format__("%Y/%m/%d")) # 2018/09/09


if __name__ == '__main__':
    datetime_datetime_strftime()
    datetime_datetime_strptime()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strftime(dataHist['last_updated'], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This piece of your code above creates a string from datetime, so anyway you would have to add time first, then convert to string.

For reverse you should use `strptime()` instead of `strftime()`, this way you'll get datetime from string.